# Why didn't Elisa release Amphibian Man into the ocean in the first place?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-shape-of-water

So, she plans to release him (the Amphibian Man) into a nearby canal when it rains to give access to the ocean.
Why wait? Why didn't she release him into the ocean in the first place?

Comment: ["She's a flawed character who selfishly wanted to spend as much time as possible with the only man who ever loved her. We see the rains starting, which could have been the day she brought him to the docks. But instead she waits as the rain gets worse and worse leading to her self-imposed deadline. We also see her anguishing, flooding her bathroom, challenging Strickland, and generally getting reckless. This isn't a plot hole, it's an examination of her character and the impact passion had on her judgment."](https://www.reddit.com/r/plotholes/comments/7rfug3/the_shape_of_water/dsy4i46/)

Comment: @BCdotWEB Before the "escape" plan, what are the clues for the viewer or Elisa, that he's in love with her?

Comment: I don't know; I've only seen the movie once and I'm unlikely to watch it again. I don't know if the Reddit comment I quoted above is a valid explanation.